# addFlags not working for pendingIntent (SingleTop mode expected)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

How to ensure the Activity launched as a SingleTop mode?
I don't want to set the launchMode in Manifest, but using flags only.

What's wrong with my code? Help appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, 0);

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=26){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Verision>26, id:"+id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Channel name",
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    channel.setDescription("description");
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);


                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(textTitle)
                            .setContentText(textContent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentIntent(pi);
                    notificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

                }
```

**Edit**

Replacing addFlags with setFlags doesn't work for me...

Answer (score -1):

Try **setFlags** instead of **addFlags**.

Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

and kindly check the arguments of Intent() once.